# How to count clicks made on an image

Tags: 7

I created a click-able image block and posted it on the left sidebar. A click made on the image leads to an external website. How do I count the number of clicks made on that image. The Google analytics don't seem to give immediate results. Is there any module for this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It depends how reliable you want it to be and what kind of count forgery and errors you are willing to accept the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on how [Advertisement](https://drupal.org/project/ad) module is doing it.

Simplified outline is:

1. Each image is linked to a page named like /count/*someuniqueid*
2. Module implements that page to increase counter and then sends `302 Found HTTP` header to user's browser.
3. Browser is redirected to a desired page and user don't really see what happened at all.

Actual workflow is, due to performance issues, way more complicated and involves php files that does not bootstrap Drupal, caching and all that.

Answer (score 0):

----inside abc.js---------

```
Drupal.behaviors.abc = {
 attach: function (context, settings) {
var count = 1;
if (typeof(Drupal.settings.orgs.count) != 'undefined') {
    var count = Drupal.settings.orgs.count;
}
$('#imageid').mousedown(function() {
 count++;
});
 $.post(Drupal.settings.basePath + 'custom-ajax-callback',{count: count});
```

----inside module   abc.module------------

```
    function custom_ajax_callback() {
    if(isset($_POST['count'] )) {
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    }
    else {
    $count = 1;
    }
    $orgs['count'] = $count;
    drupal_add_js(array('orgs' => $orgs), array('type' => setting));
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','abc.module').'/abc.js', array('org' => $org['count']);
}
```

By using js function mousedown() you can count the number of clicks on the image

Comment: Don't forget you will not count clicks from people with JS disabled or adblocking software installed.

Comment: What can be the possible solution when js is disabled ?

Comment: Thanks for all. @Mołot I used to apply some code when I was used to use ordinary HTML pages (non-drupal). Can you please explain in more detail on how to implement this a Drupal 6 environment.

Comment: @Sarmad I don't get what code you were using. Check out Advertisement (link in my answer), it has D6 version and I hacked it for http://e-warsaw.pl to get (among other) image click counting.

Comment: @user13198 How to use this code, I am not yet comfortable with creating modules myself. Is there any further advise please.

Comment: @Mołot I created an ad by using the Advertisement module, but it does not seem to create block. Only content is created. I created the block without the Ad module using this code 

`<a href="http://zuqaq.com"><img alt="" src="http://localhost/bbc/images/zuzu.png" style="width:200px; height:180px"></a>`

Comment: @Sarmad I never told you to *use* that module, right? I know it's buggy. But the basic principle and large portions of code are great. It just always seems to need to be hacked to meet requirements.

Comment: @Mołot I have resolved this matter by uploading a php code from the site [http://www.phpjunkyard.com/php-click-counter.php]. I applied the code to my block which can also distinguish unique and non unique visitors based on time interval between clicks.  Awfully thankful for your attempt to help me.